# Incremental backups with tar where current file has most recent and previous files only have different versions

Tags: linux, backup, tar

I am somewhat familiar with how to use `tar`'s `--listed-incremental` flag to take incremental backups. The end result is a `backup-0` file that has the first full back-up and then `backup-1`, `backup-2`, ..., `backup-x` with the changes in order of the backups.

In the past I have used `rsync` and hard-links to make backups where `backup-0` is current state and each `backup-x` folder has the files that were specific to that backup. Basically what is outlined http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/ and http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/Using-rsync-for-Backups/(offset).

I want mimic that functionality with tar. I cannot use hard-links because the tar files will ultimately be uploaded to a cloud provider that doesn't maintain/understand links and what not. I also want to tar the backups because I can also encrypt them before they are uploaded to the cloud.

So the idea is to have a growing list of files like so:

- `backup-0.tar.bz2` - this is the current backup and will be the biggest because it is a full backup
- `backup-1.tar.bz2` - this is yesterday's backup but it will only have the files that are different from what is in current (`backup-0.tar.bz2`)
- `backup-2.tar.bz2` - this is the backup from two days ago but it will only have the files that are different from yesterday (`backup-1.tar.bz2`)
- `backup-3.tar.bz2` - ...
- `backup-4.tar.bz2` - ...
- `backup-5.tar.bz2` - ...

If that doesn't make sense hopefully this will.

First time:

1. `$ touch /tmp/file1`
2. `$ touch /tmp/file2`
3. make `backup-0.tar.bz2`

At this point `backup-0.tar.bz2` has `/tmp/file1` and `/tmp/file2`.

Second time:

4. `$ touch /tmp/file3`
5. `$ rm /tmp/file2`
6. ..do the magic

At this point:

- `backup-0.tar.bz2` has `/tmp/file1` and `/tmp/file3`
- `backup-1.tar.bz2` has `/tmp/file2`; it doesn't have `file1` cause it didn't change so it's in `backup-0.tar.bz2`

Third time:

7. `$ touch /tmp/file1`
8. `$ touch /tmp/file4`
9. ..do the magic

At this point:

- `backup-0.tar.bz2` has `/tmp/file1`, `/tmp/file3`, and `/tmp/file4`
- `backup-1.tar.bz2` has `/tmp/file1` because it was changed
- `backup-2.tar.bz2` has `/tmp/file2`

Like so:

```
|       | first time | second time | third time              |
|-------|------------|-------------|-------------------------|
| file1 | backup-0   | backup-0    | backup-0 and   backup-1 |
| file2 | backup-0   | backup-1    | backup-2                |
| file3 |            | backup-0    | backup-0                |
| file4 |            |             | backup-0                |
```

I figured this is one way to approach it but it seems horribly inefficient to me. Maybe there are features/flags I can use that would make this more efficient.

1. first time = take `backup-0`
2. second time

   1. rename `backup-0` to `backup-1`
   2. take `backup-0`
   3. remove everything from `backup-1` that matches `backup-0`
3. third time

   1. rename `backup-1` to `backup-2`
   2. rename `backup-0` to `backup-1`
   3. take `backup-0`
   4. remove everything from `backup-1` that matches `backup-0`
4. fourth time

   1. rename `backup-2` to `backup-3`
   2. rename `backup-1` to `backup-2`
   3. rename `backup-0` to `backup-1`
   4. take `backup-0`
   5. remove everything from `backup-1` that matches `backup-0`

I feel like it's that last step (remove everything from `backup-1` that matches `backup-0`) that is inefficient.

My question is, how can I do this? If I use `tar`'s `--listed-incremental` it'll do the reverse of what I am trying.

Comment: How to do this. If I use `tar`'s `--listed-incremental` it'll do the reverse of what I am trying.

Answer (score 1):

> If I use `tar`'s `--listed-incremental` it'll do the reverse of what I am trying.

It's good you realize this. I can see upsides and downsides of either direction (I won't discuss them here). Technically it's possible to reverse the process:

1. Rename `backup-N` to `backup-(N+1)` looping from N<sub>max</sub> down to 0.
2. Restore full backup (now `backup-1`) to a temporary directory.
3. Create `backup-0` from the current data with a *new* snapshot file.
4. Remove `backup-1` (previous full backup).
5. Treat the temporary directory as a "new" version. Create `backup-1` as incremental backup, providing the snapshot file from the previous step. (Note you need to change your working directory from the one with current data to the temporary one, so relative paths stay the same).

You may wonder if this will keep the old (kept) `backup-N` files coherent with the new ones. A reasonable doubt, since the manual says:

> `-g`, `--listed-incremental=FILE`
>   Handle new GNU-format incremental backups. `FILE` is the name of a snapshot file, where `tar` stores additional information which is used to decide which files changed since the  previous incremental dump and, consequently, must be dumped again. If `FILE` does not exist when creating an archive, it will be created and all files will be added to the resulting archive (the level `0` dump). To create incremental archives of non-zero level `N`, create a copy of the snapshot file created during the level `N-1`, and use it as `FILE`.

So it suggests the snapshot file should be updated all the way *from* the full backup, as if you would need to rebuild `backup-N` files every time you perform a full backup. But then:

> When  listing  or extracting, the actual contents of `FILE` is not inspected, it is needed only due to syntactical requirements. It is therefore common practice to use `/dev/null` in its place.

This means if you extract `backup-N` files in increasing sequence to get a state from some time ago, any `backup-M` file (M>0) only expects a valid `M-1` state to exist. It doesn't matter if this state is obtained from a full or incremental backup, the point is these states should be identical anyway. So it shouldn't matter if you created the `backup-M` file based on a full backup (as you will do, every `backup-M` will start as `backup-1` where `backup-0` is a full backup) or based on a chain of incremental backups (as the manual suggests).

---

I understand your point is to keep `backup-0` as an up-to-date full backup and to be able to "go back in time" with `backup-0`, `backup-1`, `backup-2`, … If you want to keep these files in a "dumb" cloud service, you'll need to carefully rename them according to the procedure, replace `backup-1` and upload a full new `backup-0` every time. If your data is huge then uploading *a full backup every time* will be a pain.

For this reason it's advisable to have a "smart" server that can build the current full backup every time you upload a "past-to-present" incremental backup. I have used [`rdiff-backup`](https://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) few times:

> `rdiff-backup` backs up one directory to another, possibly over a network. The target directory ends up a copy of the source directory, but extra reverse diffs are stored in a special subdirectory of that target directory, so you can still recover files lost some time ago. The idea is to combine the best features of a mirror and an incremental backup. `rdiff-backup` also preserves subdirectories, hard links, dev files, permissions, uid/gid ownership, modification times, extended attributes, acls, and resource forks. Also, `rdiff-backup` can operate in a bandwidth efficient manner over a pipe, like `rsync`.

Please note the software hasn't been updated since 2009. I don't know if it's a good recommendation nowadays.

Comment: Thanks. This could work but it would require a lot of space to do the full extract to the temp directory. I have an idea to do what I want and am working on a script. 1) dump inventory of files to backup including mod time and size 2) archive files, including inventory files then later 1) extract inventory file from archive 2) take new inventory file 3) compare two files 4) extract different files and put in new archive.